# ASP.NET Core WebUI and WebAPI relations

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a solution which has 2 projects: WebUI and WebAPI.

- WebUI: There is only FroneEnd part with Angular2. It doesn't know about database.
- WebAPI: This is RESTful API's which has database connection string and services.

Question: Can anybody describe how I can make requests from WebUI to WebAPI in a CORRECT way. Set default ports, links, use configuration or else.
Thanks =)

[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4PLo.png)

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1102877/ASP-NET-Core-RC-Using-WEB-API-And-AngularJS-Part

Comment: There is only 1 project... No integration between two projects...

Comment: this? https://wintellectnow.com/Videos/Watch?videoId=getting-started-with-angular-2-and-aspdotnet-core and https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspdotnetcore-efcore-bootstrap-angular-web-app/table-of-contents

Comment: I added project structure image